# How to read messages from IBM mq asynchronously in Tomcat

Tags: java, ibm-mq, tomcat8

I want to read messages in Tomcat application from IBM mq asynchronously using ejb annotations. Can someone please suggest me how to do that. I searched in Google but could not find relevant answers to accomplish this.

Comment: The "nice" way to do this is to use the W-MQ JCA resource adapter to connect W-MQ to message-driven beans. This requires that your Tomcat version support JCA. I don't know if plain vanilla Tomcat does, but some of the extended versions like TomEE do. If you can't use the resource adapter, you'll have to use the W-MQ client runtime and find a way to plug it into your webserver using JNDI. There's a fair amount of work here if you can use JCA, and a heck of a lot if you can't. This stuff is easier on Wildfly, which definitely supports JCA.

Comment: Why do you want to use EJB on tomcat web server? Tomcat doesn't support EJB out of box, it will be needed to use TomEE. Another alternative would be switching to Spring Framework. There are lots of tutorials showing how to configure JMS using Spring. Generally it should be easier than establishing EJB infrastructure.

Comment: I was going through the below link for receiving msgs from MQ asynchronously using spring boot .http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/your-first-jms-application-with-spring-boot. Will it be done in Tomcat application?

Comment: Well, spring boot usually doesn't need tomcat, it can start its own embedded tomcat instance, but the idea is correct. Here are some other tutorials: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms, https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms, https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring.